# Why Webview change language

Tags: android, android-webview

When I load a url in my app, I found that page loaded other language. I want to set language always in English in loaded webview page. I have foud that the page has two language options. I have used bellow code..

```
    WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setUserAgentString(String.valueOf(Locale.ENGLISH));
    myWebView.loadUrl(url);
```

Please Help..

Comment: It depends on how the page(s) are implemented. Standard way would be to use preferences based on http Accept-Language header. User agent string is not the way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

**Set your locale in onCreate() method before** `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` **line.**

```
 Context ct = MainActivity.this;
 Resources res = ct.getResources();
    DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
    Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ct);
    String lang = sharedPref.getString("locale", "en");
    Locale myLocale = new Locale(lang);
    conf.locale = myLocale;
    res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
```